# Taxonomy list of specific post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

How to get list of custom taxonomy using custom post type name.
let say there is one post type called "products" and in that there are list of categories(ie. shirt, tshirt, jeans etc.)

So I want that categories list using post type name "products".

Answer (score 0):

you can get post list by taxonomy in taxonomy-{post_type}.php In this file by default gt list of post for specified taxonomy.

REF : [Custom Post Type taxonomy page still showing all posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888384/custom-post-type-taxonomy-page-still-showing-all-posts/44898782#44898782)

OR in Custom templete,

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('custom_taxonomy');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need it in specific template using some query.

Comment: This is based on taxonomy name but i want list of category based on post type name.

Comment: Inside the loop mentioned $args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type',   Try this

Comment: But here you need to add your custom taxonomy name right and i didn't want to add anywhere taxonomy name. $custom_terms = get_terms('custom_taxonomy');

Comment: use get_terms(), it gives you list of all taxonomy, then inside the loop you can filter custom post type

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'products' );
$count = count( $terms );
if ( $count > 0 ) {
  echo '<h3>Total products: '. $count . '</h3>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

get_term_link() will give you a link to your term as well.